# Vuejs bind variable in JSX with scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

I am essentially looking for something like:

```
<div v-for="k in keys" :key="k">
 {{ k }}
 ...
   <div v-with:myvalue="functionOf(k)">
     {{ myvalue }}
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how you would call such thing, but I can tell I have similar code in places and that could be handy.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? please ask a question so we can help you

Comment: It's really difficult to understand your question. Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Jalil I am looking for similar functionality for the 'v-with' directive, which is imaginary - Essentially cache a function of a variable that the v-for directive provides to use on corresponding scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the computed property to make functions that transform the values into something else.

For example lets say you have this code here.

```
<div id="example">
  {{ message.split('').reverse().join('') }}
</div>
```

You can add add a computed property to run some js code and just call it in the html template

```
<div id="example">
  <p>Original message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p> //computed function
</div>


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Example with `v-for`

```
<div v-for="k in keys" :key="k">
 {{ k }}
   <div>
     {{ reversedMessage(k) }}
   </div>
</div>


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage(k){ //you receive the value for each k you have in keys
      return k.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Of course you can also send some parameters like your K object to work with it in the v-for

Comment: But then you can't have one per each for-loop iteration dynamically

Comment: You need different behaviors for each value?

Comment: I need a uniform behaviour for each value. Look at the original questions snippet. I know what can already be done with computed properties

Comment: I modified my answer to add a v-for example, is that what you needed? Check it out